# JpaRepository, don't now how to migrate NativeQuery to something better due to complex sorting sequence

Tags: java, sorting, jpa, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

due to requirements (fictional calendar for fictional world, I can't use a real date format), the complexity of fictional dates in this project is giving me some headache.
So, I want to recover all Sucesos (events) for a Persona (character) ordered by this fictional date, and I have written this functional nativeQuery, that works ok:

```
@Query(value = "select * from Suceso s "
        + "inner join personasuceso ps on s.idsuceso = ps.idsuceso "
        + "inner join persona p on ps.idpersona = p.idpersona "
        + "inner join fecha f on s.fkfecha = f.idfecha "
        + "where p.idpersona = :id "
        + "order by f.fkedad asc, f.anyo asc, f.fkmes asc, f.fkdia asc, s.norden", nativeQuery = true)
public Set<Suceso> findAllInPersona_IdPersona(@Param("id")Integer id);
```

**Is there a better way to implement such a complex ordering??**
I have tried everything I know and everything I found, no success.

Here are the Entities (simplified):

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "persona")
    public class Persona implements java.io.Serializable {
       private Integer idpersona;
       @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "personas")
       public Set getSucesos() {
          return sucesos;
       }
    }
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "suceso")
    public class Suceso implements java.io.Serializable {
       private Integer idsuceso;
       private Fecha fecha;
       private integer norden;
        @ManyToOne()
        @JoinColumn(name = "fkfecha")
        public Fecha getFecha() {
            return this.fecha;
        }
        @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
        @JoinTable(name = "personasuceso", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "idsuceso") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "idpersona") })
        public Set getPersonas() {
            return personas;
        }
    }
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "fecha")
    public class Fecha implements java.io.Serializable {
        private Integer idfecha;
        private Dia dia;
        private Edad edad;
        private Mes mes;
        private Integer anyo;
        
        @ManyToOne()
        @JoinColumn(name = "fkedad")
        public Edad getEdad() {
            return this.edad;
        }
    
        @ManyToOne()
        @JoinColumn(name = "fkmes")
        public Mes getMes() {
            return this.mes;
        }
        
        @ManyToOne()
        @JoinColumn(name = "fkdia")
        public Dia getDia() {
            return this.dia;
        }
    }
        
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "edad")
    public class Edad implements java.io.Serializable {
        private Integer idedad;
    }
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "mes")
    public class Mes implements java.io.Serializable {
        private Integer idmes;
    }
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "dia")
    public class Dia implements java.io.Serializable {
        private Integer iddia;
    }
```

Thanks!!

Comment: "better" in what way? The query looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: What did you try exactly and why didn't it work? Why isn't "select s from Suceso s join s.personas p, join s.fecha f where p.idpersona = :id order by f.edad asc, f.anyo asc, f.mes asc, f.dia asc, s.norden" working?

Comment: it works, but i looks "dirty" to me using native queries in source code :(